# SQL Matching Query

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

### table a

```
ida     valuea
1       a
2       b
3       c
1       d
1       e
2       f
```

### table b

```
idb      valueb
1 
2
```

I make valueb as a combobox and need to source it from a query that selects valuea if only ida = current idb.and table b become:

### table b

```
idb      valueb
1        (a,d,e)
2        (b,f)
```

Comment: select value a from tablea inner join tableb on idb=ida but this select the record even it is not the current if it contained in table b

Comment: your problem desc is not enough to understand. i don't know what you a re looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to tell exactly what you are asking, but I think you are either looking for just a simple INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT  TableB.IDB, TableA.ValueA
FROM    TableB
        INNER JOIN TableA
            ON TableA.IDA = TableB.IDB
```

Or you need to concatenate the rows from tableA into a single row with IDB. The methods of doing this are DBMS dependant, since you have not specified a DMBS I have answered with as many as I know. Each of which has an example on SQL Fiddle.

---

**[SQL-Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d784d/1)**

```
SELECT  TableB.IDB,
        STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + ValueA
                FROM    TableA
                WHERE   TableA.IDA = TableB.IDB
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS ValueB
FROM    TableB
```

---

**[MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d784d/1)/[SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/c713b/1)**

```
SELECT  IDB, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(ValueA) AS ValueB
FROM    TableB
        INNER JOIN TableA
            ON TableA.IDA = TableB.IDB
GROUP BY IDB
```

---

**[PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c713b/1)**

```
SELECT  IDB,
        ARRAY_AGG(ValueA) AS ValueB
FROM    TableB
        INNER JOIN TableA
            ON TableA.IDA = TableB.IDB
GROUP BY IDB
```

---

**[Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c713b/1)**

```
SELECT  IDB, 
        LISTAGG(ValueA, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY IDB) AS ValueB
FROM    TableB
        INNER JOIN TableA
            ON TableA.IDA = TableB.IDB
GROUP BY IDB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct valuea
FROM tablea
WHERE ida = @idb
```

`@idb` is a parameter containing your selected choice's value

Comment: thank you very much but it give me an error when I put the symbole @

Comment: The @ is for a parameter. You have to declare it. How you do that depends on your application, the version of sql you are using etc. Try replace @sql with 1 or 2 etc and see if that does what you want. If it does then Google how to declare and use sql parameters for your specific programming environment.