# SQL • Result of join in an array

Tags: sql, join

Good evening,

Here is my problem: I make a select query on my table PROJECT to select (for now) my only test project. I do a join on the table to retrieve screenshots SCREENSHOT associated with it. Only he will get out as many results as there are screenshots! Ie here 5.
Could I go back to more data (name, datesortie, description, etc.) an associative array urls screenshots?
Or would you have a solution to simplify my life? Because the only solution I see is treating it directly in php.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT P.nom, datesortie, description, lien, icone, tag, S.url
FROM PROJET P

LEFT JOIN CLIENT C
ON C.idclient = P.idclient

LEFT JOIN SCREENSHOT S
ON S.idprojet = P.idprojet

ORDER BY P.nom
```

Here is what is returned (Sorry, my var_dump shows me that online ... I do not understand why):

```
array(7) { ["nom"]=> string(10) "BlackStars" ["datesortie"]=> string(10) "2012-07-02" ["description"]=> string(498) "Inspiré par Little Stars for Little Wars, Black Stars se veut être meilleur par bien des aspects. Prenez le contrôle d'une planète et partez à la conquête de l'univers en remportant chacune des batailles, en brisant chacune des planètes ennemies, en devenant le meilleur joueur. Car une fois le mode solo terminé, un mode multi-joueurs (Bluetooth ou Game Center) vous attend afin de vous mesurer au monde entier. Hissez-vous en haut du classement et devenez le maître incontesté de Black Stars. " ["lien"]=> string(69) "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/black-stars/id512945753?l=fr&ls=1&mt=8" ["icone"]=> string(131) "http://a1775.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/73/47/b7/7347b764-cff9-c52b-78da-42560a187acf/mza_1097997557772736292.170x170-75.png" ["tag"]=> string(10) "blackstars" ["url"]=> string(119) "http://a1352.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/51/df/f5/51dff56b-08c6-59db-81df-80a174ec0050/mza_509496145749890361.png" }

===================================================
===================================================

array(7) { ["nom"]=> string(10) "BlackStars" ["datesortie"]=> string(10) "2012-07-02" ["description"]=> string(498) "Inspiré par Little Stars for Little Wars, Black Stars se veut être meilleur par bien des aspects. Prenez le contrôle d'une planète et partez à la conquête de l'univers en remportant chacune des batailles, en brisant chacune des planètes ennemies, en devenant le meilleur joueur. Car une fois le mode solo terminé, un mode multi-joueurs (Bluetooth ou Game Center) vous attend afin de vous mesurer au monde entier. Hissez-vous en haut du classement et devenez le maître incontesté de Black Stars. " ["lien"]=> string(69) "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/black-stars/id512945753?l=fr&ls=1&mt=8" ["icone"]=> string(131) "http://a1775.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/73/47/b7/7347b764-cff9-c52b-78da-42560a187acf/mza_1097997557772736292.170x170-75.png" ["tag"]=> string(10) "blackstars" ["url"]=> string(119) "http://a572.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/db/1d/1d/db1d1d00-3a28-8b6f-d52f-342bf5893912/mza_3642427234916705950.png" }

===================================================
===================================================

array(7) { ["nom"]=> string(10) "BlackStars" ["datesortie"]=> string(10) "2012-07-02" ["description"]=> string(498) "Inspiré par Little Stars for Little Wars, Black Stars se veut être meilleur par bien des aspects. Prenez le contrôle d'une planète et partez à la conquête de l'univers en remportant chacune des batailles, en brisant chacune des planètes ennemies, en devenant le meilleur joueur. Car une fois le mode solo terminé, un mode multi-joueurs (Bluetooth ou Game Center) vous attend afin de vous mesurer au monde entier. Hissez-vous en haut du classement et devenez le maître incontesté de Black Stars. " ["lien"]=> string(69) "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/black-stars/id512945753?l=fr&ls=1&mt=8" ["icone"]=> string(131) "http://a1775.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/73/47/b7/7347b764-cff9-c52b-78da-42560a187acf/mza_1097997557772736292.170x170-75.png" ["tag"]=> string(10) "blackstars" ["url"]=> string(120) "http://a1701.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/60/5f/ae/605fae3e-f00b-c3b7-0f65-ca73f6fd9864/mza_4565911160744621776.png" }

===================================================
===================================================

array(7) { ["nom"]=> string(10) "BlackStars" ["datesortie"]=> string(10) "2012-07-02" ["description"]=> string(498) "Inspiré par Little Stars for Little Wars, Black Stars se veut être meilleur par bien des aspects. Prenez le contrôle d'une planète et partez à la conquête de l'univers en remportant chacune des batailles, en brisant chacune des planètes ennemies, en devenant le meilleur joueur. Car une fois le mode solo terminé, un mode multi-joueurs (Bluetooth ou Game Center) vous attend afin de vous mesurer au monde entier. Hissez-vous en haut du classement et devenez le maître incontesté de Black Stars. " ["lien"]=> string(69) "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/black-stars/id512945753?l=fr&ls=1&mt=8" ["icone"]=> string(131) "http://a1775.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/73/47/b7/7347b764-cff9-c52b-78da-42560a187acf/mza_1097997557772736292.170x170-75.png" ["tag"]=> string(10) "blackstars" ["url"]=> string(119) "http://a193.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/7c/ff/67/7cff67dc-d679-16ee-24cf-7f658c78b9c8/mza_8709328453215958742.png" }

===================================================
===================================================

array(7) { ["nom"]=> string(10) "BlackStars" ["datesortie"]=> string(10) "2012-07-02" ["description"]=> string(498) "Inspiré par Little Stars for Little Wars, Black Stars se veut être meilleur par bien des aspects. Prenez le contrôle d'une planète et partez à la conquête de l'univers en remportant chacune des batailles, en brisant chacune des planètes ennemies, en devenant le meilleur joueur. Car une fois le mode solo terminé, un mode multi-joueurs (Bluetooth ou Game Center) vous attend afin de vous mesurer au monde entier. Hissez-vous en haut du classement et devenez le maître incontesté de Black Stars. " ["lien"]=> string(69) "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/black-stars/id512945753?l=fr&ls=1&mt=8" ["icone"]=> string(131) "http://a1775.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/73/47/b7/7347b764-cff9-c52b-78da-42560a187acf/mza_1097997557772736292.170x170-75.png" ["tag"]=> string(10) "blackstars" ["url"]=> string(120) "http://a1443.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/d7/13/8f/d7138f62-6398-7993-8d0b-23e0ce16dca2/mza_8316005873463209973.png" }

===================================================
===================================================
```

Thank you in advance for your help.
Cordially.

Comment: What DBMS are you using, MySQL? SQL-Server?

Comment: I think you are asking a question that has been asked many times before, about concatenating rows to a single row in sql. I recently gave [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292896/sql-matching-query/11294127#11294127) with a solution in many different DBMS. However, you state *"the only solution I see is treating it directly in php."*, while this is not the only solution, it is probably the best solution. PHP deals with arrays much better than SQL so why not leave arrays to PHP and data storage to you database?

Comment: @GarethD - Note: All of those answer still have the same problem with aggregating strings that contain commas.  *[But it IS a damn good answer.]*

Comment: @Dems I agree 100% (unless a different delimiter is used that is invalid in urls), I only linked it to show it is possible, I am not advocating it in this scenario (or many others). *[P.s. Thanks]*

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather, you just don't want all that repeating information in the first 6 fields?

Normally, accepting the repeating information is the way to go about it.  But, you could pull back *two* record sets.  Provided that they're neatly ordered you can do a nested loop to process them.

```
SELECT P.nom, datesortie, description, lien, icone, tag, idproject
FROM PROJET P
LEFT JOIN CLIENT C
ON C.idclient = P.idclient
LEFT JOIN SCREENSHOT S
ON S.idprojet = P.idprojet
ORDER BY P.nom

SELECT P.idproject S.url
FROM PROJET P
INNER JOIN SCREENSHOT S
ON S.idprojet = P.idprojet
ORDER BY P.nom
```

Note: The first query now also has the `idproject` field, which is also present in the second record set.  The second record set is also ordered by `P.nom`, even though it's not selected in the statement; this just ensures that you can do a simple nested loop.

A simplifies pseudo-code could be...

```
FOR EACH nom IN recordSet1
  WHILE recordSet1.idProject = recordSet2.idProject
    Do something with the URL
    Move to next record in recordSet2
  LOOP
LOOP
```

***What I would not do***

Another option is to concatenate all of the URLs together into a single string.  Perhaps separated by commas to make a CSV field.

But then the existence of a comma in the url will break that.  So you probably then want to use XML or something; with added costs to generate and parse.

Unless the network overhead of the repeated fields is *actually causing a problem*, I would stick to that.  And if it is causing a problem, the two-record-set alternative is more robust and relatively simple.

Comment: +1 Simply for "what I would not do". There is a time and a place for string concatenation within SQL, and I don't think this is one of them. These are sentiments I wanted to express but could only be bothered with a comment not an answer...